# Is a negative nuance possible with しっとり when used to describe moisture of an object?

Tags: meaning, nuances, adjectives

`じっとり` always has a **negative nuance** to it when used, such as when describing perspiration.

`しっとり` has several meanings, but in this context it is used to describe the dampness of something.

An example sentence using `しっとり`:

`しっとりとぬれる : become wet`

Is `しっとり` **strictly positive**, or can it be negative like `じっとり`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「しっとり」, as long as the word is being used properly, would always be positive and that should be why it is so heavily used in advertisement for food and cosmetic products.

If an object contained moisture in a way that was undesirable to a person, s/he would opt to use 「べたつく」、「**じ**っとり」、「じめじめ（している）」, etc. instead to add a negative nuance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the dictionary, しっとり seems to have a positive meaning.
１ 軽く湿りけが行き渡っているさま。
２ 静かに落ち着いて、好ましい趣のあるさま。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98671/meaning/m0u/しっとり/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/98671/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A/)

Comment: This link *might* be difficult for intermediate speakers (and beginners) to follow.  I didn't do the down vote, but I think that if you were to give more detail, this answer would get more up votes.